# Desktop cannot restart (it will shut down) - Multiple OS's tried

Tags: windows, linux, reboot, desktop-computer

I built a desktop a year or so ago, which runs like a dream. I have installed many OSes on it but the problem persists.
If it tell the PC to restart it does everything right, shuts down but the PC remains on before it can restart.
The OS shuts down and nothing is running, but the desktop stays on.
If it helps, the PC shuts down fine. Just an annoying issue if I get updates in Windows/ Ubuntu etc.

Comment: What motherboard are you using?  This sounds like a problem with the power settings in the BIOS.

Comment: It is an ASRock motherboard, running an AMD Quad Core. It has worked fine previously, it seems to have been an issue since I have moved.

Comment: Check your power settings in the BIOS (as said above). If the issue persists crossplatform, that is where your answer lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things to try:

- Try restarting it from Windows' Safe mode.
- Try disconnecting all external devices and see if it restarts as expected.

Comment: Tried all of the above, even tried with nothing but a monitor connected. I assume it must be a hardware issue but I am not too sure what might cause it?

Comment: Thanks, seems like it was some USB receiver that I did not realise I was using.

Comment: @Christopher Gwilliams - NP.  Glad it worked out. :)